# Spherical circle - Area

Tags: differential-geometry, circles, area, spherical-geometry

I am looking at the following exercise:

The spherical circle of centre $p \in S^2$ and radius $R$ is the set of points of $S^2$ that are a spherical distance $R$ from $p$.

If $0 \leq R \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ a spherical circle of radius $R$ is a circle of radius $\sin R$.

Show that, if $0 \leq R \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, the area inside a spherical circle of radius $R$ is $2\pi (1 − \cos R)$.

$$$$

To find the area inside a spherical circle of radius $R$ do we have to calculate the area inside a circle of radius $\sin R$ ?

Comment: No, it's not necessary to compute the circle of radius $\sin R$. Use the integral formula and you will see that only needs to use the circumference.

Comment: Do you mean the formula $$\mathcal{A}_{\sigma}(R)=\iint_R\|\sigma_u\times\sigma_v\|dudv$$ ? @Tom-Tom

Comment: I do not know what are the $\sigma$ in you formula. I meant the formula to compute the area of the spherical cap :
$$\mathcal{A}=\int_0^R2\pi\sin\theta\;\mathrm d\theta$$
where $2\pi\sin\theta$ is the circumference of the circle of radius $\sin\theta$.

Comment: What is a spherical cap? A spherical circle? @Tom-Tom

Comment: Yes: it is a spherical **disk**, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap

Comment: Can we not calculate the area using the first fundamental form? When the first funamental form is $$Egu^2+2Ffufv+Gdv^2$$ then the area is equal to $$\mathcal{A}_{\sigma}(R)=\iint_R\sqrt{EG-F^2}dudv$$ But can we find in ths case the first fundamental form? @Tom-Tom

Comment: The first fundamental form on the sphere is simple $\mathrm ds^2=\mathrm d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\;\mathrm d\phi^2$. Using this, you will find immediately the integral I have written.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-) @Tom-Tom

Comment: One more question... Is the interval of $R$ important? Is it significant that $0\leq R\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and not for example $R>\frac{\pi}{2}$ ? @Tom-Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metric tensor on the sphere is given by the identity
$$\mathrm ds^2=\mathrm d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\,\mathrm d\varphi^2$$
where $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ is the colatitude and 
$\varphi\in\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$ is the
longitude on the unit sphere $\mathcal S$. 
A spherical "disk" is usually called *spherical cap* and refers to
 $$\mathscr C_R=\left\{(\theta,\varphi)\in\mathcal S^2\, \big| 
\;0\le\theta\le R\right\}.$$
The area of the spherical cap is given by the integral
$$\mathcal A(\mathscr C_R)=\int_{\mathscr C_R}\sqrt{1\times\sin^2\theta-0\times0}
\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\varphi
=\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\varphi\int_0^R
\left|\sin\theta\right|\mathrm d\theta.$$
The sinus $\sin\theta$ is always positive and 
one can integrate to find $$\mathcal A(\mathscr C_R)=2\pi(1-\cos R).$$
Note that if $R=\pi$ (its upper limit),
the cap covers the whole sphere and we have
$\mathcal A(\mathscr C_R)=4\pi=\mathcal A(\mathcal S^2)$.

It is possible to compute the area of a spherical "ring", 
a [*frustum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum),
which is given by $\mathcal A(\mathscr F_{R_1,R_2})=2\pi\left|\cos R_1-\cos R_2\right|$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! :-)